# Adding compared at price in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopify

First things first. I'm a newbie to woocommerce and web dev.

How can I add a sale price and a compare at price on products in woocommerce stores, like the option available on Shopify??

Eg: If the product sale price is $10 and the actual price is 20, I want to add the $10 as the sale/discounted price and add the $20 as the compared at/actual price on which discount is given.

Shopify has an option to add this price during product creation but couldn't find anything to do that in Woocommerce. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo of woocommerce using storefront theme. You can set the sale price as shown in the snap below.

[backend_snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ1hX.png)

It will be displayed in front-end as shown below.

[frontend_snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDM9H.png)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The store is a print on demand one and woocommerce works in sync with the service provider. There is an option to add prices like this while manually creating products.

Here, products and prices are automatically synced to store.

Also, I can not find the option to edit HTML while using the current theme